# loopification of highly procedureal, though fully functional, multiclass perceptron

Tags: java, loops, perceptron

I've implemented the multiclass perceptron in the one vs. all style.

I just thought about it and tried to implement it in the most basic way. I think it's correct though my f_measure is a bit low. Which I believe is due in part to the fact that I haven't cleaned up my input, it's a feature vector of document words and I left all kinds of pronouns, 'the' and the like, which doubtless contribute not insignificantly to this confusion. In addition to the highly naieve tokenization of just every " ", quite rudimentary. ANYWAY, that's neither here nor there.

I'd like to know if some one among you might be able to devise a way to loopify this program, i.e. expunge this highly repetitive code and replace it with elegant loops.

```
public class MulticlassPerceptron 
{
      static int MAX_ITER = 100;
      static double LEARNING_RATE = 0.1;           
      static int theta = 0; 

      static final String LABEL_atheism = "atheism";
      static final String LABEL_sports = "sports";
      static final String LABEL_science = "science";
      static final String LABEL_politics = "politics";

      public static void perceptron( Table< int[] , String , Integer > train_freq_count_against_globo_dict,
                                     Table< int[] , String , Integer > test_freq_count_against_globo_dict,
                                     Set<String> GLOBO_DICT )
      {
          int globo_dict_size = GLOBO_DICT.size();
          int number_of_files__train = train_freq_count_against_globo_dict.size();

          double[] weights__science = new double[ globo_dict_size + 1 ];//one for bias
          double[] weights__sports = new double[ globo_dict_size + 1 ];//one for bias
          double[] weights__politics = new double[ globo_dict_size + 1 ];//one for bias
          double[] weights__atheism = new double[ globo_dict_size + 1 ];//one for bias

          for (int i = 0; i < ( globo_dict_size + 1 ); i++) 
          {
            weights__science[i] = randomNumber(0,1);
            weights__sports[i] = randomNumber(0,1);
            weights__politics[i] = randomNumber(0,1);
            weights__atheism[i] = randomNumber(0,1);
          }     

           double[][] feature_matrix__train = new double[ number_of_files__train ][ globo_dict_size ];
           int[] outputs__science = new int [ number_of_files__train ];
           int[] outputs__sports = new int [ number_of_files__train ];
           int[] outputs__politics = new int [ number_of_files__train ];
           int[] outputs__atheism = new int [ number_of_files__train ];

           int z = 0;
           for ( Cell< int[] , String , Integer > cell: train_freq_count_against_globo_dict.cellSet() )
           {               
               int[] container_of_feature_vector = cell.getRowKey();

               for (int q = 0; q < globo_dict_size; q++) 
               {
                   feature_matrix__train[z][q] = container_of_feature_vector[q];
               }
               outputs__science[z] =  String.valueOf( cell.getColumnKey() ).equals(LABEL_atheism)  ||
                                      String.valueOf( cell.getColumnKey() ).equals(LABEL_sports)   ||
                                      String.valueOf( cell.getColumnKey() ).equals(LABEL_politics) ? 0 : 1;

               outputs__sports[z] =   String.valueOf( cell.getColumnKey() ).equals(LABEL_atheism)  ||
                                      String.valueOf( cell.getColumnKey() ).equals(LABEL_science)  ||
                                      String.valueOf( cell.getColumnKey() ).equals(LABEL_politics) ? 0 : 1;

               outputs__politics[z] = String.valueOf( cell.getColumnKey() ).equals(LABEL_atheism)  ||
                                      String.valueOf( cell.getColumnKey() ).equals(LABEL_sports)   ||
                                      String.valueOf( cell.getColumnKey() ).equals(LABEL_science)  ? 0 : 1;

               outputs__atheism[z] =  String.valueOf( cell.getColumnKey() ).equals(LABEL_science)  ||
                                      String.valueOf( cell.getColumnKey() ).equals(LABEL_sports)   ||
                                      String.valueOf( cell.getColumnKey() ).equals(LABEL_politics) ? 0 : 1;
               z++;
           }

          //LEARNING WEIGHTS
          double localError, globalError;
          int p, iteration, output;

          //SCIENCE
          iteration = 0;
          do 
          {
              iteration++;
              globalError = 0;
              //loop through all instances (complete one epoch)
              for (p = 0; p < number_of_files__train; p++) 
              {
                  // calculate predicted class
                  output = calculateOutput( theta, weights__science, feature_matrix__train, p, globo_dict_size );
                  // difference between predicted and actual class values
                  localError = outputs__science[p] - output;
                  //update weights and bias
                  for (int i = 0; i < globo_dict_size; i++) 
                  {
                      weights__science[i] += ( LEARNING_RATE * localError * feature_matrix__train[p][i] );
                  }
                  weights__science[ globo_dict_size ] += ( LEARNING_RATE * localError );

                  //summation of squared error (error value for all instances)
                  globalError += (localError*localError);
              }

              /* Root Mean Squared Error */
              System.out.println("Science vs. All");
              if (iteration < 10) 
                  System.out.println("Iteration 0" + iteration + " : RMSE = " + Math.sqrt( globalError/number_of_files__train ) );
              else
                  System.out.println("Iteration " + iteration + " : RMSE = " + Math.sqrt( globalError/number_of_files__train ) );
          } 
          while(globalError != 0 && iteration<=MAX_ITER);


          //SPORTS
          iteration = 0;
          do 
          {
              iteration++;
              globalError = 0;
              //loop through all instances (complete one epoch)
              for (p = 0; p < number_of_files__train; p++) 
              {
                  // calculate predicted class
                  output = calculateOutput( theta, weights__sports, feature_matrix__train, p, globo_dict_size );
                  // difference between predicted and actual class values
                  localError = outputs__sports[p] - output;
                  //update weights and bias
                  for (int i = 0; i < globo_dict_size; i++) 
                  {
                      weights__sports[i] += ( LEARNING_RATE * localError * feature_matrix__train[p][i] );
                  }
                  weights__sports[ globo_dict_size ] += ( LEARNING_RATE * localError );

                  //summation of squared error (error value for all instances)
                  globalError += (localError*localError);
              }

              /* Root Mean Squared Error */
              System.out.println("Sports vs. All");
              if (iteration < 10) 
                  System.out.println("Iteration 0" + iteration + " : RMSE = " + Math.sqrt( globalError/number_of_files__train ) );
              else
                  System.out.println("Iteration " + iteration + " : RMSE = " + Math.sqrt( globalError/number_of_files__train ) );
          } 
          while(globalError != 0 && iteration<=MAX_ITER);


          //POLITICS
          iteration = 0;
          do 
          {
              iteration++;
              globalError = 0;
              //loop through all instances (complete one epoch)
              for (p = 0; p < number_of_files__train; p++) 
              {
                  // calculate predicted class
                  output = calculateOutput( theta, weights__politics, feature_matrix__train, p, globo_dict_size );
                  // difference between predicted and actual class values
                  localError = outputs__politics[p] - output;
                  //update weights and bias
                  for (int i = 0; i < globo_dict_size; i++) 
                  {
                      weights__politics[i] += ( LEARNING_RATE * localError * feature_matrix__train[p][i] );
                  }
                  weights__politics[ globo_dict_size ] += ( LEARNING_RATE * localError );

                  //summation of squared error (error value for all instances)
                  globalError += (localError*localError);
              }

              /* Root Mean Squared Error */
              System.out.println("Politics vs. All");
              if (iteration < 10) 
                  System.out.println("Iteration 0" + iteration + " : RMSE = " + Math.sqrt( globalError/number_of_files__train ) );
              else
                  System.out.println("Iteration " + iteration + " : RMSE = " + Math.sqrt( globalError/number_of_files__train ) );
          } 
          while(globalError != 0 && iteration<=MAX_ITER);


          //ATHEISM
          iteration = 0;
          do 
          {
              iteration++;
              globalError = 0;
              //loop through all instances (complete one epoch)
              for (p = 0; p < number_of_files__train; p++) 
              {
                  // calculate predicted class
                  output = calculateOutput( theta, weights__atheism, feature_matrix__train, p, globo_dict_size );
                  // difference between predicted and actual class values
                  localError = outputs__atheism[p] - output;
                  //update weights and bias
                  for (int i = 0; i < globo_dict_size; i++) 
                  {
                      weights__atheism[i] += ( LEARNING_RATE * localError * feature_matrix__train[p][i] );
                  }
                  weights__atheism[ globo_dict_size ] += ( LEARNING_RATE * localError );

                  //summation of squared error (error value for all instances)
                  globalError += (localError*localError);
              }

              /* Root Mean Squared Error */
              System.out.println("Atheism vs. All");
              if (iteration < 10) 
                  System.out.println("Iteration 0" + iteration + " : RMSE = " + Math.sqrt( globalError/number_of_files__train ) );
              else
                  System.out.println("Iteration " + iteration + " : RMSE = " + Math.sqrt( globalError/number_of_files__train ) );
          } 
          while(globalError != 0 && iteration<=MAX_ITER);






          //TEST   
           int number_of_files__test = test_freq_count_against_globo_dict.size();
           double[][] feature_matrix__test = new double[ number_of_files__test ][ globo_dict_size ];

           String[] test_file_true_label = new String [ number_of_files__test ];

           int x = 0;
           for ( Cell< int[] , String , Integer > cell: test_freq_count_against_globo_dict.cellSet() )
           {               
               int[] container_of_feature_vector__test = cell.getRowKey();

               for (int q = 0; q < globo_dict_size; q++) 
               {
                   feature_matrix__test[x][q] = container_of_feature_vector__test[q];
               }
               test_file_true_label[x] = (String)( cell.getColumnKey() );

               x++;
           }
           System.out.println();


           double tp_science = 0.0;
           double fp_science = 0.0; 
           double tn_science = 0.0;
           double fn_science = 0.0;

           double precision_science = 0.0;
           double recall_science = 0.0;
           double f_measure_science = 0.0;

           double tp_sports = 0.0;
           double fp_sports = 0.0; 
           double tn_sports = 0.0;
           double fn_sports = 0.0;

           double precision_sports = 0.0;
           double recall_sports = 0.0;
           double f_measure_sports = 0.0;

           double tp_atheism = 0.0;
           double fp_atheism = 0.0; 
           double tn_atheism = 0.0;
           double fn_atheism = 0.0;

           double precision_atheism = 0.0;
           double recall_atheism = 0.0;
           double f_measure_atheism = 0.0;

           double tp_politics = 0.0;
           double fp_politics = 0.0; 
           double tn_politics = 0.0;
           double fn_politics = 0.0;

           double precision_politics = 0.0;
           double recall_politics = 0.0;
           double f_measure_politics = 0.0;


           int actual_class = 0;

          for (p = 0; p < number_of_files__test; p++) 
          {

              int predict_science = calculateOutput( theta, weights__science, feature_matrix__test, p, globo_dict_size );

              actual_class = ( test_file_true_label[p] ).equals( LABEL_science ) ? 1 : 0;

              if( actual_class == 1 && predict_science == 1 )
                  tp_science++;
              if( actual_class == 1 && predict_science == 0 )
                  fn_science++;
              if( actual_class == 0 && predict_science == 1 )
                  fp_science++;
              if( actual_class == 0 && predict_science == 0 )
                  tn_science++;  

              int predict_sports = calculateOutput( theta, weights__sports, feature_matrix__test, p, globo_dict_size );

              actual_class = ( test_file_true_label[p] ).equals( LABEL_sports ) ? 1 : 0;

              if( actual_class == 1 && predict_sports == 1 )
                  tp_sports++;
              if( actual_class == 1 && predict_sports == 0 )
                  fn_sports++;
              if( actual_class == 0 && predict_sports == 1 )
                  fp_sports++;
              if( actual_class == 0 && predict_sports == 0 )
                  tn_sports++;

              int predict_politics = calculateOutput( theta, weights__politics, feature_matrix__test, p, globo_dict_size );

              actual_class = ( test_file_true_label[p] ).equals( LABEL_politics ) ? 1 : 0;

              if( actual_class == 1 && predict_politics == 1 )
                  tp_politics++;
              if( actual_class == 1 && predict_politics == 0 )
                  fn_politics++;
              if( actual_class == 0 && predict_politics == 1 )
                  fp_politics++;
              if( actual_class == 0 && predict_politics == 0 )
                  tn_politics++;

              int predict_atheism = calculateOutput( theta, weights__atheism, feature_matrix__test, p, globo_dict_size );

              actual_class = ( test_file_true_label[p] ).equals( LABEL_atheism ) ? 1 : 0;

              if( actual_class == 1 && predict_atheism == 1 )
                  tp_atheism++;
              if( actual_class == 1 && predict_atheism == 0 )
                  fn_atheism++;
              if( actual_class == 0 && predict_atheism == 1 )
                  fp_atheism++;
              if( actual_class == 0 && predict_atheism == 0 )
                  tn_atheism++; 

          }

          System.out.println( "SCIENCE");
          System.out.println( "tp_science: " + tp_science );
          System.out.println( "fp_science: " + fp_science );
          System.out.println( "tn_science: " + tn_science );
          System.out.println( "fn_science: " + fn_science );
          System.out.println();

          precision_science = tp_science / (tp_science + fp_science);
          System.out.println( "precision_science = " + precision_science );

          recall_science = tp_science / (tp_science + fn_science);
          System.out.println( "recall_science = " + recall_science );

          f_measure_science = ( 2 * ( precision_science * recall_science ) ) / ( precision_science + recall_science );
          System.out.println( "f_measure_science = " + f_measure_science );
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println();




          System.out.println( "SPORTS");
          System.out.println( "tp_sports: " + tp_sports );
          System.out.println( "fp_sports: " + fp_sports );
          System.out.println( "tn_sports: " + tn_sports );
          System.out.println( "fn_sports: " + fn_sports );
          System.out.println();

          precision_sports = tp_sports / (tp_sports + fp_sports);
          System.out.println( "precision_sports = " + precision_sports );

          recall_sports = tp_sports / (tp_sports + fn_sports);
          System.out.println( "recall_sports = " + recall_sports );

          f_measure_sports = ( 2 * ( precision_sports * recall_sports ) ) / ( precision_sports + recall_sports );
          System.out.println( "f_measure_sports = " + f_measure_sports );
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println();



          System.out.println( "POLITICS");
          System.out.println( "tp_politics: " + tp_politics );
          System.out.println( "fp_politics: " + fp_politics );
          System.out.println( "tn_politics: " + tn_politics );
          System.out.println( "fn_politics: " + fn_politics );
          System.out.println();

          precision_politics = tp_politics / (tp_politics + fp_politics);
          System.out.println( "precision_politics = " + precision_politics );

          recall_politics = tp_politics / (tp_politics + fn_politics);
          System.out.println( "recall_politics = " + recall_politics );

          f_measure_politics = ( 2 * ( precision_politics * recall_politics ) ) / ( precision_politics + recall_politics );
          System.out.println( "f_measure_politics = " + f_measure_politics );
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println();



          System.out.println( "ATHEISM");
          System.out.println( "tp_atheism: " + tp_atheism );
          System.out.println( "fp_atheism: " + fp_atheism );
          System.out.println( "tn_atheism" + tn_atheism );
          System.out.println( "fn_atheism: " + fn_atheism );
          System.out.println();

          precision_atheism = tp_atheism / (tp_atheism + fp_atheism);
          System.out.println( "precision_atheism = " + precision_atheism );

          recall_atheism = tp_atheism / (tp_atheism + fn_atheism);
          System.out.println( "recall_atheism = " + recall_atheism );

          f_measure_atheism = ( 2 * ( precision_atheism * recall_atheism ) ) / ( precision_atheism + recall_atheism );
          System.out.println( "f_measure_atheism = " + f_measure_atheism );
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println();



          System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
          System.out.println();


          //average them!
          System.out.println( "AGREGATE");
          double precision = ( ( precision_atheism + precision_sports + precision_science + precision_politics ) / 4 );
          System.out.println( "precision = " + precision );

          double recall =  ( ( recall_atheism + recall_sports + recall_science + recall_politics ) / 4 );
          System.out.println( "recall = " + recall );

          double f_measure =  ( ( f_measure_atheism + f_measure_sports + f_measure_science + f_measure_politics ) / 4 );
          System.out.println( "f_measure = " + f_measure );



      }
```

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I put it there, they said put it here.

Comment: Yes, I did bite my tongue after I said that. Sorry, codereview.